# can you give a stroke a glitter pattern

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stroke

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can get my circle outer stroke to look glittery like the outer square frame which I purchased, been trying so hard to work it out for myself but its driving me crazy now Hoping someone can point me in the right direction - I'm using Photoshop CC

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It really depends on how this was constructed. Do you know if the rectangle is filled with a pattern?  Is there a pattern included in the document? Check the Patterns panel (click Window > Patterns). If so you could use the pattern as the stroke.

Comment: No it is just a png image

Comment: @Julie - thanks, that makes it easier to answer. Have added an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

If as you say, the glitter is simply a PNG image, create a circle on a new layer with a black stroke applied. Duplicate the PNG image layer, and make sure it is above the circle layer, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click between the layers to clip the glitter image to the black stroke.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooooo much Billy - I have tried what you said but I've ended up a black ring with the glitter inside the circle

Comment: Sussed it thank you so much for your help, I had a white centre to my circle, when I looked at your layers I could see my elipse was different to yours, I really really appreciate your help Thanks

Comment: @Julie - no worries, glad it worked for you in the end.